# The subgroup on which, a normalizer is defined is a normal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $ G$. Then the normalizer of $H$ is defined as,

$N_G(H)=${$g\in G: gHg^{-1}=H$}.

However, $gHg^{-1}=H$ if and only if $gH=Hg$, which implies that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ (since left and right cosets of $H$ are identical). Is this observation correct? Please someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes correct, $N_G(H)=G$ if and only if $H \unlhd G$. Observe that always $H \unlhd N_G(H)$, in fact the normalizer is the *largest* subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ in which $H$ is normal.

Comment: @Nicky Hekster Thanks for a fruitful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just noticed that a subgroup is a normal subgroup of its normalizer.

This is, in a sense,  the whole idea of the normalizer.  In fact, as @Nicky Hekster observes, the normalizer is the largest such subgroup.